# Jupyter download as pdf

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex

How can I solve this problem when I want to download as pdf through Jupyter?

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "['xelatex', './notebook.tex', '-quiet']" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
```

`` '''(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx
.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.20'
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.2a <2019/01/15> (tvz))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grffile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
No file notebook.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.


! LaTeX Error: Command \b already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.384 \newcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.384 \newcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log. ``